# Emulate MIPS firmware in qemu

Tags: embedded, emulation, mips, qemu

I'm trying to emulate a firmware with qemu, but I'm getting an error while trying to execute it.

First of all I extracted the firmware filesystem to a folder, and copied de qemu-mipsel file to it:

```
bin  cdrom  dev  etc  home  init  lib  linuxrc  mnt  opt  proc  qemu-mipsel  root  sbin  sys  tango  tmp  udev  usr  var
```

Then I executed the emulator with chroot:

> chroot . ./qemu-mipsel ./bin/ls

And I get the following error:

```
chroot: failed to run command `./qemu-mipsel': No such file or directory
```

Googling the error I found that it means that qemu depends on libraries not included in the chroot environment so I searched for them:

```
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fffe79ff000)
librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007fcd9da57000)
libgthread-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgthread-2.0.so.0 (0x00007fcd9d855000)
libglib-2.0.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0 (0x00007fcd9d55d000)
libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007fcd9d2db000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007fcd9d0be000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fcd9cd34000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fcda007a000)
libpcre.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3 (0x00007fcd9caf7000)
```

And some libraries are missing in ./lib/:

linux-vdso.so.1
libgthread-2.0.so.0
libglib-2.0.so.0
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
libpcre.so.3

How could I solve this problem? Can I create a symbolic link to the system library or should I copy them? Also linux-vdso.so.1 is not present on the system, where could I get it? Regards.

Answer (score 1):

linux-vdso.so.1 is in reality the kernel. The other files, you get them from your GNU/Linux distribution of choice (e.g. Debian, from the source packages eglibc, pcre3 and glib2.0). You must indeed copy them into the chroot. For /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 the pathname must be exact, as that path is hard-coded into the binary.

It seems you’re running Debian already, from the multiarch’d paths, which is good, because you’ll need to distinguish between host and target libraries.

Alternatively, you can compile and link qemu-mipsel statically.

Comment: I coppied all the libraries inside the chroot but now I'm getting this error: ./qemu-mipsel: error while loading shared libraries: librt.so.1: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32

Comment: I think it’s picking up the wrong librt.so file. Is the mipsel image you’re running also using Multi-Arch? I suspect ${chrootbasepath}/lib/librt.so.1 is used instead of ${chrootbasepath}/lib/mipsel-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 which allows the x86 binary qemu to pick it up. You could try running the qemu binary like this: env LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu chroot $chrootbasepath ./qemu-mipsel … (or, otherwise, always compile it statically)